# What makes red meat less healthy than seafood, after millennia of evolving to eat meat?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, human-evolution, diet

We are told that red meat is carcinogen; fish and white meat are not. What make us not "compatible" to red meat after thousands of years of evolution and meat eating, and yet seafood is opposite ?

Comment: *Compatible* is not a biological term in this case. We're _compatible_ with red meat, and all the other good stuff, because we can eat it, derive nutrition from it, and survive long enough to reproduce. That's all it takes to be a viable member of the biosphere. Also, please consider that the Sun is a carcinogen too. Being carcinogenic does not disqualify it from being consumed by humans. Think cigarettes and barbecue.

Comment: Right. Even if _compatible_ is not a correct term, I suppose the question is understood by everyone. Beside, you made a good example for my point : The sun is carcinogen, destroys tissues and we are exposed daily, therefore evolution drives the darker skin of certain race to counter that.

Comment: @Kenny - Please cite a reliable source that states red meat is a carcinogen. To my knowledge, it is not. What are **co-carcinogens**, though, are the products of grilling/frying/searing it over high heat. The same is true for grilling/frying/searing fish *if* there are any fat drippings (either from the fish, or from the sauce used to baste the fish. Since most fish isn't fatty, this is less of a risk.) Red meat can cause other problems, but a direct link

Comment: http://www.who.int/features/qa/cancer-red-meat/en/ "Red meat was classified as Group 2A, probably carcinogenic to humans" (limited evidence), and the fact that several renowned doctors in France recommend some friends of mine to stop eating red meat while treating cancers.

Comment: "We are told..." by people with quasi-religious agendas, like vegetarianism.  It's a good idea not to believe everything you're told without considering the source and/or looking for independent confirmation.

Comment: I've also voted to close because the question seems to be based on an incorrect assumption (that red meat is a carcinogen).

Comment: Sorry, but read meat IS a carcinogen that contributes significantly to colon cancer. Also, charred meat, as you mentioned, is a co-carcinogen. Kenny should not have to provide evidence for some of the minor details of his question. I have edited the question so that it makes more sense, but it seemed clear to me from the start.

Comment: If you read that article carefully, it supports my position quite clearly. There is no convincing evidence of a link, the only *possibility* is colorectal cancer, and who knows but that may be gut flora, etc. @KarlKjer - It is **presumed** to contribute to colorectal cancer. There is a great difference between presumption and fact.

Comment: @jamesqf True.But aren't all knowledge in the form of "we are told",or are you born knowing how to count? Second,human will never agree 100%, see round-earth fact. It's a good idea to take into account,not blindly,expert opinions in the fields we don't know when a large amount in that group agrees, especially in highly controlled domain like medical. Until agreed otherwise (e.g religion-never debunked, or slavery-agreed otherwise). Will you follow advices to treat syphilis according to the majority of medical advices _now_,or let it grow with a yet unproven chance of becoming superman _later_?

Comment: @anongoodnurse bolstering my point about "majority" against "convincing evidence". Even for agreed treatments, there is no 100% success rate. Clinical trial is always a statistical "majority acceptance amongst subjects". People are still debating if smoking is linked to cancer. That's because the number of known and unknown variables affecting health outcome is so huge, noone is certain and have to rely on "majority". Look at how we have thousands years of weather info and still cannot tell with certainty if it rains tmr. Talk about butterfly effect...It's a gray area and never definite.

Comment: The fact that there's no 100% success rate in treatment has absolutely nothing to do with **causation.** And, fyi, no one is seriously debating that cigarettes (or asbestos, or alcohol) cause cancer. Rain tomorrow? These are false equivalencies. They don't bolster your argument, they weaken it.

Comment: I beg to differ. First, about your argument Noone is seriously debating about the effect of cigarettes or alcohol, please refer to last month 's http://time.com/5376552/how-much-alcohol-to-drink-study/ "A New Study Says Any Amount of Drinking Is Bad". Wouldn't you call it debating over a 'fact' people seem to agree for years ? Aren't clinical study to prove a causation "Is drug A effective (more effective than drug B) for disease D ?" Rain tomorrow : ever noticed rain forecast tomorrow changes when it suddenly rain tonight ? The fact of raining today causes the chance of raining tmr to change.

Comment: @Kenny: No.  To use your example, we can deduce counting from observation.  WRT "we are told", it seems that there should be an obvious difference between "told" meaning the (repeatable & testable) results of scientific studies, and someone making up claims because it fits their agenda.  So where are the scientific studies showing that red meat causes cancer?  Whereas a couple of minutes with Google finds studies like this one https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4691673/ showing no overall difference between vegetarians & meat eaters.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question that reveals a very common misconception about evolution. Evolution is not the same as optimization or advancement. It is about selection. Cancer and heart disease mostly kill people AFTER they have had their offspring. Selection does not generally act upon post-reproductives. So anything high in fat, calories and proteins would be likely to help humans survive starvation, and live to reproduce. We do not evolve to beat the diseases of old age, and our genes can be 10,000 years behind present optima. We don't evolve to be happy, live long lives, or be nice, unless these things help more of our offspring to survive.